# Converting Json column to tabular structure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with column. one column is json  - "session".
The json is not nested.
If I want to make the key of the json as new column name, how can I do that easily?
The json is big, so is there something dynamic? without specifying each key in the json?
I found only solution that return me key-value pairs but I want it on more relational style.

example:

```
User_name | Is active | Session
Kate          yes        {"session_id": 34386384,
                           "platform: Jha,
                            "last_login": 12/2/97}
```

I want it to be:

```
User_name | Is active | session_id | platform | last_login
Kate          yes        34386384     Jha         12/2/97
```

what i tried:

```
with cte as (
             select 
            from user_sessions
            ,lateral flatten(input => Session)
            )
select *
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Lateral flatten can help extract the fields of a JSON object and is a very good alternative to extracting them one by one using the respective names. However, sometimes the JSON object can be nested and normally extracting those nested objects requires knowing their names

More details on how to: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extract-multi-level-JSON-object-using-lateral-flatten

Comment: So the best thing to do is to take the distinct keys from lateral eval and somehow put them inside the select statement? if my json is not nested, isn't there a simpler option?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dynamically-extracting-JSON-using-LATERAL-FLATTEN

Comment: That's what I saw! but still when I'm doing the example from there' I need to specify the json keys. I guess there is no simple solution without the exact keys.

Comment: you can use the combination of the articles for your custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple accessing of the JSON can be done (if it is already been [PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html)'ed)

the `data` CTE is just there for some input data. I also convert the date to a internal DATE object.

```
WITH data(user_name,is_active, session) as (
    SELECT 'Kate', true, PARSE_JSON('{"session_id": 34386384,"platform": "Jha", "last_login": "12/2/97"}')
)
SELECT 
    d.user_name,
    d.is_active,
    d.session:session_id::number as session_id,
    d.session:platform::text as platform,
    to_date(d.session:last_login::text, 'DD/MM/YY') as last_login 
FROM data AS d;
```

gives:

| USER_NAME | IS_ACTIVE | SESSION_ID | PLATFORM | LAST_LOGIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kate | TRUE | 34386384 | Jha | 1997-02-12 |